# Why am I unable to activate java web in netbeans?

Tags: java, web, plugins, netbeans

I have installed Apache netbeans IDE 13. I can see the option "java web" in  installed plugins. But it is grey colour, but it is not allowing me to activate it. Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close (button `cancel`) the dialog and reopen the project dialog (`File > New Project`), you should have the following view, and click `Next` button:

[image]